# Proving if $|f(z)|\leq\frac{2}{R^2+1}$ is true

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> Suppose that $$f(z)=\frac{e^{-z}}{z^2+1}.$$
>   Is it true that $$|f(z)|\leq\frac{2}{R^2+1}$$ for all $z$ such that $\Re(z)\geq 0$ and $|z|>R$?

My attempt:

consider the triangle inequality \begin{align}
|z^2+1|&\leq |z|^2+1 \\
\frac{1}{|z^2+1|}&\geq \frac{1}{|z|^2+1} \\
&\leq\frac{1}{R^2+1} \\
\frac{|e^{-z}|}{|z^2+1|}&\leq \frac{|e^{-z}|}{|z|^2+1} \\
&=\frac{1}{e^{\Re(z)}}\frac{1}{R^2+1} \\
&\leq\frac{1}{R^2+1}
\end{align}

While my working suggests the statement is incorrect, I wonder if the logic from my **second to third line** is correct? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, from the second to the third line is not correct. Knowing that $b$ is less than both $a$ and $c$ tells you nothing about the relationship between $a$ and $c$.

Comment: You may write $|z^2+1|\ge |z|^2-1$. Then $\displaystyle \frac{1}{|z^2+1|}\le \frac{1}{|z|^2-1}$

Comment: Yep. By the reverse triangle angle inequality. Thanks!